# How to make multiple independent attachments to the same docker container?

Tags: docker

Maybe a trivial question but that's my problem:

I attached to a running docker container, after some use I needed to run a Unit Test and gdb at "the same time".

So I openned another shell tab (konsole tab) and attached again to the same docker container `$ docker attach container_name` but everything I did echoed in both attachments. If I execute `cd /home/user/folder_foo` the other tab will "do the same", ended up both konsole tabs in the same folder. Like the same command was echoed to both tabs. Maybe it's a unique user structure and what I isn't even possible.

I really need to do two things in parallel in the same docker container, how it could be done?

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.9, build c2ea9bc
```

I am using Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Attaching to a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) attaches the current input and output streams (so when run interactively, your terminal) to the running entrypoint command in a container. So attaching multiple times from different terminals will show the same output from the same command, and input from either will affect both attachments.

To run different commands in the same container at the same time, you need to actually [run different commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). Keep the first attachment you have, and for your second command, run

```
docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash
```

(assuming you have `/bin/bash` inside your container image).

This will give you two separate shells inside the same running container.